# Using Java in Oracle Database 11g

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have Java Files *(that use external libraries)* that I am trying to run in **Oracle SQL Developer 11g Enterprise Edition 11.2.0.3.0 .**

I compiled and uploaded my code *(using JDK 1.5x, I know it does not support anything higher)* to the Database Java folder using these lines below from command prompt.

```
loadjava -user username/password@MyInstance -force -verbose -resolve -fileout Javawriter.log  -genmissing MyLibrary.jar

loadjava -user username/password@MyInstance -force -verbose -resolve -fileout Javawriter.log -genmissing MyJavaFile.java
```

I am wondering how can I use this Java file using **SQL procedure** or **the Worksheet**. How can I **call methods** in my Java Classes and **return** some value?

P.S. Something like this **does not** return me any value

```
Varchar(20) summaryCall = MyJavaClass.MyMethod(5,3);
```

What am I doing wrong? :S

Comment: @Justin Cave is absolutely correct. I also found an article for people interested http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/chthree.htm#CACICFFB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create a [PL/SQL wrapper function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/chthree.htm#CACFCDJF).  Something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myMethod( p_arg1 IN NUMBER,
                                     p_arg2 IN NUMBER ) 
  RETURN VARCHAR2 
AS
  LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 
    'MyJavaClass.MyMethod (java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer) 
          return java.lang.String';
```

You'd then call the PL/SQL function

```
summaryCall varchar2(20) := myMethod( 5, 3 );
```

Comment: Thank you Justin :) Umm .. Do these methods need to static?

Comment: @awesomeniket - Yes, the methods that you expose in PL/SQL need to be static.  That often involves writing your own Java class(es) to interact with whatever libraries you're loading in order to implement the actual business logic you need.

Comment: Hey Justin, could you have a look at this link too?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001145/output-file-using-oracle-database   Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have created a tutorial related to your question. You can see that [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1txuhyLGdH8)

Hope this helps :)